# SSH key fingerprints don't match

Tags: ssh, encryption

I'm trying to [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) from my laptop into my desktop. On the desktop, `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub` yields `08:ac:cb:9c:e8:c2:4f:2c:1d:6e:54:ad:83:c7:27:47`, but when I try to connect, I'm told the [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) key [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint) is something completely different.

I can connect to the machine through HTTP, so I know it's the right one. I'm worried someone is trying to [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It tells you more than what you present here. You need to understand difference between server host key and your client identity key:

- This is fingerprint of your local client identity key:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub
  ```
- By calling `ssh remotehost` you are prompted to verify server host key, which is stored on server and you or somebody with access to the server can create you the same fingerprint by executing

  ```
  ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
  ```

These two fingerprints will never match.

This can be found in [`man sshd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd).

Comment: OK, so, when the client tells you the identity of the server can't be verified and asks you to confirm that the fingerprint is indeed of the server you want to connect to, which fingerprint should you compare it to?

Comment: @Andyc the server host key. Collected through a different means than this ssh connection. The mindful ssh server administrators publish these keys on websites, for example there are github ones: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints
Or through DNS if you trust your DNS resolver enough.

Comment: Your answer was actually clear enough on this. Don't know why I didn't understand it right away. Thank you anyway, I finally understood something that drove me crazy for days.